# Inheriting a inner class of an AMD Module

Tags: typescript

In Typescript I have a module like this:

```
export module ABC{
  export class classA {
  }
}
```

I would like to inherit classA from class B.

```
class classB {
}
```

If I do something like this

```
export module ABC{
  export class classA extends classB {
  }
}
```

The compiler tells me that classB must be a class. By the way classB lies in a separate file.

How can I make it work ???
Thanks in advance

---

Ok,

Instead of extending the inner class I have decided to define a module and an inner instance property of an inner class of another module. Just like that:

**File1.ts**

```
export module moduleA {

    export class classA {

      subscribed: bool;

      constructor () { }

      public unsubscribeLogOff(eventName) {
        this.subscribed = false;
      }
      public subscribeLogOff(eventName) {
        this.subscribed = true;
      }
    }
}
```

**File2.ts**

```
import m = module("moduleA"); 

export module moduleB {

    var instanceA: m.moduleA.classA = null;

    export function activate() {
      if( this.instanceA == null ) instanceA = new m.moduleA.classA();
      instanceA.subscribeLogOff(eventName);
    }

    export function deactivate() {
      if( instanceA == null ) return;
      instanceA.unsubscribeLogOff(eventName);
    }
}
```

The problem here is that I expected that after calling **subscribeLogOff** the property **subscribed** of **classA** maintained its value, so that when calling **unsubscribeLogOff** the value of **subscribed** was true.

But this is not true when I call **unsubscribeLogOff** the value of **subscribed** is **undefined**.

I cannot understand. Can you help me ???

Thanks

Comment: Please consider marking answers on your questions as "Accepted" if they are useful and correct. See [here for instructions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this work, your code should look something like this:

**File1.ts**

```
export module ABC {
    export class classA {
    }
}
```

**File2.ts**

```
import otherFile = module('file1');

export module ABC {
    export class classA extends otherFile.ABC.classA {
    }
}
```

Note that if you have a top-level object marked with `export`, wrapping your stuff one level deeper in `module` blocks is usually unnecessary.